# substring in sh returns "Bad substitution"

Tags: linux, bash, substring, sh

In this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
a='sdsdsd'
c=${a:0:1}
```

I use second line to read bytes of string one by one (in a loop), but it returns error in sh ("sh: 3: Bad substitution").
any way to do it in sh mode?
for some reasons i should use sh (not bash, and i know bash will be OK)

Comment: In this case i don't have any command like cut.

Comment: @oliv They have clearly stated multiple times they are using sh

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support `${name:offset:length}` expansion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The substring parameter expansion is not part of the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). It's a ksh/bash feature. If you need it, you can't use `#!/bin/sh`

If you need to use `sh`, you need to call out to `expr`

```
$ dash -c '
    a="ABCDEF"
    i=1
    while [ "$i" -le "${#a}" ]; do
        c=$(expr substr "$a" "$i" 1)
        echo "$i:$c"
        i=$((i + 1))
    done
'
1:A
2:B
3:C
4:D
5:E
6:F
```

Answer (score 2):

With posix shell without expr

```sh
#!/bin/sh
var='abcd'
count="${#var}"
until [ "$count" -eq 0 ];do
  vartemp="${var#[a-z]}"
  lavar="${var%$vartemp}"
  var="$vartemp"
  count="$((count-1))"
  echo "$var $count $lavar"
done
```

Comment: Could you tell me about vartemp="${var#[a-z]}", i don't understand it! :(

Comment: I found! :) "${string#regex}—deletes shortest matching substring from beginning of string"

Comment: and about lavar="${var%$vartemp}" --> ${string%substring}: Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

Comment: Nice. If you want just the first character  even if it's not a letter then `${var#?}`